# R LiblineaR weights do not change with class labels

Tags: r, classification, svm, feature-selection, libsvm

I want to use the LiblineaR library in R which is efficient for large datasets. (I want to use the l1-norm on wieghts for feature selection but not relevant for this question). What I observed is that even if the class labels are changed the weights do not. Here is an example;

```
x <- rbind(cbind(rnorm(100),rnorm(100)), cbind(rnorm(100,3), rnorm(100,3)))
y <- c(rep(1,100), rep(-1,100))
m <- LiblineaR(x,y)
m$W
       W1        W2    Bias
[1,] -1.238046 -1.437913 3.86309
y2 <- c(rep(-1,100), rep(1,100))
m2 <- LiblineaR(x,y2)
m2$W
       W1        W2    Bias
[1,] -1.238046 -1.437913 3.86309
```

So even after flipping the labels the weights stay the same. This is problematic for feature selection.

Any ideas why this is the case?

If the svm from library e1071 is used then the primal weights (calculated using custom function) flip as expected.

update: I checked the same example with the c++ implementation of [liblinear](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) and the resulting weights flip their sign as expected.

Comment: @gung thanks for pointing this out. moving to SO will be good. thanks